# Matplotlib legend + tight_layout = squashed subplots

Tags: python, matplotlib

Consider the following example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import gridspec
import numpy as np

x = np.linspace(0, 10, 100)
y = 2*x + 0.5

plt.figure(figsize=(6, 4))
gs = gridspec.GridSpec(2, 2)

plt.subplot(gs[0, 0])
plt.plot(x, y, "o")

plt.subplot(gs[0, 1])
plt.plot(x, y, "o")

plt.subplot(gs[1, :])
plt.plot(x, y, "o", label="test")
plt.legend(loc="upper center", bbox_to_anchor=(0.5, 2.7))

plt.subplot(gs[2, :])
plt.plot(x, y, "o")

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

When I remove `bbox_to_anchor` from `plt.legend`, the above code should produce something like this:

[image]

But when I place the legend outside of the subplot using `bbox_to_anchor` (as in the code above), the subplots get squashed:

[image]

Obviously, this is not desired. There seems to be a conflict between `bbox_to_anchor` and `tight_layout()` (if you remove either from the code above, something sensible comes out). Is there something I'm doing wrong, or is this known/expected behaviour?

This problem is reproduced under various back-ends. I don't get any warnings or errors. I'm using matplotlib version `2.2.2`.

Comment: What does the number `2.7` try to achieve? Where would you like the legend to be placed?

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest the number `2.7` should position the legend far above the bottom subplot (somewhere near the top of the figure). This value is a relic of the plots I was creating when the problem appeared, in combination with `subplots_adjust`. In this minimal example, I haven't tested what the correct value should be for a nice layout (could be `2.3` or something), but different values give the same results (i.e. squashing the subplots).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The result is expected, although clearly not desireable. Since the legend is part of the lower subplot, it will take part in the `tight_layout` mechanism and hence shift everything to the top.

You may call `tight_layout` first,

```
plt.tight_layout()
plt.legend(loc="upper center", bbox_to_anchor=(0.5, 2.3))
```

to get the tight spacing and then afterwards create the legend.

You may also create a figure legend,

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(6, 4))
# ...
fig.legend(loc="upper center", bbox_to_anchor=(0.5, .9))
plt.tight_layout()
```

Comment: Calling `tight_layout` first works like a charm, thanks Ernest